# How to install related package automatically with .deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, package, debian, deb

I try to create .deb package for my program.

It needs ImLib2-dev package.

I want to make .deb package install ImLib2-dev package automatically.

```
Package : MyProject
Version : 1.0.0.0
Section : base
Priority : optional
Architecture : i386
Depends:
Maintainer : xxx <xxx@xxx.com>
Description : Install Package
```

This is control file in DEBIAN directory of .deb package.

What should I do?

**ADD**

I read some documents about control file and learn about Depend, Pre-Depend.

But it just check required package is installed and exit when isn't installed

not install packages. Is there any option for installing non-exist package?

---

```
sudo dpkg -i ~~.deb
apt-get -f install
```

installs dependencies, but what I want to do is do it at once with dpkg.

So I try to find the way with changing control file in deb package.

Comment: If the package you are depending on is available in the archives, `apt-get`, `Software Center` and even `gdebi` (I think) will ask you if you want the software to install dependencies for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the behavior during installation via `dpkg` and `apt-get`. `apt-get` (and other UI for APT) works with APT repositories and will check `Depends` and ask to install those packages if they aren't installed. `dpkg` is only able to see the files presented to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What You said is dpkg doesn't install their dependencies automatically? I find 'apt-get -f install' installs dependencies, but what I want to do is install with dpkg -i ~~.deb. Isn't there any way?

Comment: DPKG does not automatically install dependencies; if it finds a dependency, it has no method to look for and fetch that dependency. That is what APT (apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, et al) is used for.

Comment: Then control file in .deb package folder is used for just declaring dependency? Someone said editing control file will solve this problem.

Comment: The control file specifies what the dependency is. It does not declare where or how to find that dependency. If you want to automatically install dependencies, you need to use APT.

Comment: I understand what you said. Thank you very much for solving my problem.